# I don't know how to configure usb modem for huawei 3g mobile network of cat cdma

Tags: networking, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

Please help me someone who know how to configure it:
CAT CDMA, HUAWEI C880/EVDO 3G Network:USB Modem
I don't know how to configure to connect it. Please help me if someone who know about it.

Comment: please can you take a look at the output from lsusb and dmesg | grep usb (to make sure the device has been seen correctly and is ready to use) and post here? Also this post may help http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1660404

Answer (score 2):

I got the apns detail from huawei mobile phone and it is the configuration for the mobile broadband. It work perfect.